# Kotlin + Moshi serialization of object type

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, moshi

I have following code in Kotlin:

```
sealed class ParentClass
data class ChildA(val prop: String): ParentClass()
object ChildB: ParentClass()
```

but when I try to serialize it into JSON with Moshi I get following Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize object declaration ChildB
Failed to serialize obj: ChildB of type: class ChildB to a map
```

I don't want to include full stack trace due to confidentiality, but essentially it fails on this [line](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/1fdc61dc311ed6a60f308be7246208f42bbc8b21/moshi-kotlin/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/kotlin/reflect/KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.kt#L224-L226). I wonder if there is a way to serialize Kotlin object types into JSON and back?

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/ZacSweers/MoshiX/tree/main/moshi-sealed should support that use case, I believe.